# SELECT statement inside RAISE sqlite

Tags: sqlite, exception, triggers, raise

I'm trying to get the error description for RAISE using a select statement, but its not working. Here's my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fetch_survey_list INSERT ON surveylst_offline_info
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN ( (SELECT van from surveylst_offline_info WHERE van = new.van) IS NOT NULL)
        THEN 
        RAISE (FAIL, SELECT error_des FROM ErrorTable WHERE error_id = 1;)
    END;
END;
```

TIA!

Comment: The [trigger itself](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) can have a WHEN clause.

Answer (score 0):

The error message of RAISE() is not an SQL expression but a *name* (like a table or column name). Specifying a string in `'`single quotes`'` happens to work because this a valid mechanism to [escape names](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), but the most basic usage is to use a plain name (and *not* a message) that identifies the error:

```
... RAISE(FAIL, error_1) ...
```